# How to demonstrate that this series is divergent/convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $S$ be the series

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^3(\sqrt{3}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}}$$

How can it be proved to be divergent or convergent?

Comment: Please, make a guess. And notice that $$\frac{(\sqrt{3} + (-1)^n)^n}{3^n} < \left(\frac{(\sqrt{3} + 1)}{3}\right)^n.$$

Comment: If  there is a polynomial $P$ such that $|F(n)|\leq P(n)$ except for finitely many $n\in \mathbb N $...(.& note that  "none" is finitely many).... and if $|K|>1, $ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F(n)K^{-n}$ converges. Here $K=3/(1+\sqrt 3\;)$  and $P(n)=n^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $0<\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^3(\sqrt{3}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+(-1)^n}{3}\right)^n<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{3}\right)^n$.

We know that $\displaystyle r=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{3}<1$.

Now, using the ratio test, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r(x+1)^3}{x^3}=r$.

We also have that $|r|<1$.

Therefore, the series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that eventually
$$0<{\frac{n^3(\sqrt{3}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}}\leq \left(\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)^n.$$
Can you explain why? Is the series convergent or divergent?